# Using Keybinding

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, abstract-action

I'm doing some very basic coding, just trying to learn the basic concepts behind keybinding. It all seems very straightforward but there's something wrong with my logic or structure that is keeping my code from executing the way I want it to.

Here is my code

```
public class Board {

ButtonListener buttonlistener;  
EnterAction enterAction;

public Board(){

    JFrame skeleton = new JFrame();
    skeleton.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    skeleton.setVisible(true);
    skeleton.setSize(400, 400);

    buttonlistener = new ButtonListener();
    enterAction = new EnterAction();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    button.addActionListener(buttonlistener);
    panel.add(button);
    skeleton.add(panel);        
    panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("s"), "doEnterAction");
    panel.getActionMap().put("doEnterAction", enterAction);

}

public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
        System.out.println("button pressed");
    }       
}

public class EnterAction extends AbstractAction{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("enter pressed");    
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Board();
}
```

So, it should be pretty simple. As you can see I'm just trying to make it print out "enter pressed" whenever you press enter, but it isn't printing out anything (unless you click the button also shown in the code above). Also, in eclipse, the EnterAction class is underlined in yellow, I think it may not be being called right, but I don't know why it wouldn't be.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, what is the warning you're getting in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate issue I can see is with the following statement

```
panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("s"), "doEnterAction");
```

`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("s")` is going to return `null`.  The requirements for the `String` passed to this method are very particular and not well documented (IMHO).

You could use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S")` instead, but I prefer to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0)` as there is no chance of ambiguity in the statement.

I would also recommend that you define the focus boundaries as well for the input map...

Instead of `panel.getInputMap()`, try using `panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` to ensure that the key event will be triggered if the window is focused

Take a look at [`JComponent#getInputMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap%28int%29) for more details.

If you haven't already done so, you should also take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("s"), "doEnterAction");
```

To

```
panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "doEnterAction");
```

Also

`skeleton.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

the parameter must be `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` or just put number `3`.

Comment: *"or just put number 3*" ... and what happens if the constant changes values?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Simply, a disaster happens :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Azad and MadProgrammer are correct, I only had to make one more simple change in addition to what they recommended to get the program running. I have numbered the three items for you as a comment in the code: (copy and paste and you are good to go).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Board {

    ButtonListener buttonlistener;
    EnterAction enterAction;

    public Board() {

        JFrame skeleton = new JFrame();
        //Change #1 below 
        skeleton.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        skeleton.setVisible(true);
        skeleton.setSize(400, 400);

        buttonlistener = new ButtonListener();
        enterAction = new EnterAction();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JButton button = new JButton("button");
        button.addActionListener(buttonlistener);
        panel.add(button);
        skeleton.add(panel);
        //Change #2 below
        panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "doEnterAction");
        panel.getActionMap().put("doEnterAction", (Action) enterAction);

    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("button pressed");
        }
    }

    public class EnterAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("enter pressed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Board();
    }
    //Change #3 below
}
```

here is the screenshot:
[image]